# overflow-x scroll did not work

Tags: scroll

https://jsfiddle.net/4psawf1h/7/

And all the time The strap is non-movable, and li goes to a new line, how to make it all li in one line with movable strap.

here is css

```
div {
   background-color: blue;

}   


   ul { 
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid red;  
   overflow-x: scroll;
   width: 100vh;
}


ul > li {
   float: left;
   width: 156px;
}
```

Here is template html

```
<div>   
<ul> 
   <li>bxcbxcb cb</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>bxcbxcb cb</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>bxcbxcb cb</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>bxcbxcb cb</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>bxcbxcb cb</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>bxcbxcb cb</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>bxcbxcb cb</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>1</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this css:

```
ul { 
   background-color: blue;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px solid red;  
   overflow-x: scroll;
   width: 100vh;
   white-space:nowrap;
}
ul > li {
   display: inline;
   width: 156px;
}
```

**Update:**

Try with this:

```
ul > li {
       display: inline-table;
       width: 156px;
    }
```

Hope this is what you want to achieve!

Comment: Hey, I try it okej, but did not work if i set inside <div> look : https://jsfiddle.net/4psawf1h/8/ how to fix now???